# yeoman webapp: Minified JS for multiple HTML pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, yeoman, minify

I'm playing around with the [yeoman webapp generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp) and want to have multiple minified JavaScript files for my individual subpages for my page. However, the webapp concats all JavaScript files to one "big" `main.js` which does not match my setup.

In my setup, `main.js` is supposed to be some kind of common JavaScript file for all pages but each page should have an additional JavaScript file with stuff that only relates to this page. E.g.

`index.html` -> uses `main.js`

`subpage1.html` -> uses `main.js` and `subpage1.js`

`subpage2.html` -> uses `main.js` and `subpage2.js`

The result from `gulp build` is a big `main.js` that contains the `main.js`, `subpage1.js` and the `subpage2.js` which leads to errors: if I open `subpage1.html`, `subpage2.js` (the one that is included in the big `main.js`) might try to access HTML nodes that only exist on `subpage2.html` but not on `subpage1.html`.

E.g.:

subpage1.html includes the big `main.js` with `subpage2.js`

```
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
```

which contains subpage1.js AND subpage2.js, however if I do the following in subpage2.js

```
$('#IdThatOnlyExistsOnSubPage2').someMethod(...)
```

this fails of course.

How do I have to adjust the Gulpfile to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS and CSS builds are generating with [uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) (formerly known as [usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin)) you could find more advanced options and features from their documentation but I think you should separate build block by your needs.

If you have a common JS file for every page, you have to put them together for each pages and create new block for page specific files.

Here is example.

```html
<!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js scripts/page-dashboard.js -->
<script src="dashboard-charts.js"></script>
<script src="dashboard-widgets.js"></script>
<script src="dashboard-main.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Also you could do same thing for CSS file builds.

```html
<!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:css style/page-dashboard.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dashboard-charts.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dashboard-widgets.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dashboard-main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks for your support; I did not know it works so easy!

Comment: I am very happy to help @zersaegen ^^